# Error in constructing dplyr code

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame that contains sequential samples and the (X, Y) co-ordinates of different people at different locations.

```
df <- data.frame(Name = rep(c("Client A","Client B", "Client C"),3), 
             Sample = rep(c(1,2,3), each=3), 
             Location = rep(c("City","Country","Suburban"),3),
             X = c(4.35, 4.36, 4.42, -5.70, -5.70, -5.75, 3.60, 3.59, 3.57),
             Y = c(-15.43, -15.44, -16.31, -19.67, -19.67, -15.18, -20.49, -18.95, -18.97))
```

I wish to calculate their distance covered, from one sample to the next, at each location. This should be arranged by  each Name, Sample and Location. I constructed the following code using `dplyr`.

```
require(dplyr)
DistanceOutput <- df %>%
arrange(Name,Sample,Location) %>%
group_by(Name,Sample,Location) %>%
mutate( lagX = lag(X), lagY = lag(Y)) %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(Distance = 
       dist( matrix( c(X,Y,lagX,lagY),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE) )
) %>%
select(-lagX, -lagY)
```

This arranges my output precisely as I am after, but just contains a Distance column full of `NA` as below. I expect the first row (of Name and Location) to contain an NA for distance, but not the next two samples.

```
> ddply(DistanceOutput,.(Name, Sample),function(x) head(x,2))
  Name Sample Location     X      Y Distance
1 Client A      1     City  4.35 -15.43       NA
2 Client A      2     City -5.70 -19.67       NA
3 Client A      3     City  3.60 -20.49       NA
4 Client B      1  Country  4.36 -15.44       NA
5 Client B      2  Country -5.70 -19.67       NA
6 Client B      3  Country  3.59 -18.95       NA
7 Client C      1 Suburban  4.42 -16.31       NA
8 Client C      2 Suburban -5.75 -15.18       NA
9 Client C      3 Suburban  3.57 -18.97       NA
```

If I re-arrange the `group_by` line, I end up with a different format of Name/ Sample/ Location than above. Where am I going wrong in my above code?

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't `group_by` "Sample" before the `lag`, only "Name" and "City". Then, use "Sample" as your `order_by` for the `lag`. The reason I'm using `dplyr::lag` is that lag is already used by `zoo` in my system.

There's something very weird with the results though. I should get a non-NA "Distance" at the 3rd line, but I'm getting NA. Might be a bug....

```
require(dplyr)
DistanceOutput <- df %>%
arrange(Name,Sample,Location) %>%
group_by(Name,Location) %>%
mutate( lagX = dplyr::lag(X, order_by=Sample), lagY = dplyr::lag(Y, order_by=Sample)) %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(Distance = dist( matrix( c(X,Y,lagX,lagY),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE) )) %>%
select(-lagX, -lagY)
DistanceOutput
Source: local data frame [9 x 6]
Groups: <by row>

      Name Sample Location     X      Y Distance
     (chr)  (dbl)    (chr) (dbl)  (dbl)    (dbl)
1 Client A      1     City  4.35 -15.43       NA
2 Client A      2     City -5.70 -19.67   10.908
3 Client A      3     City  3.60 -20.49       NA
4 Client B      1  Country  4.36 -15.44       NA
5 Client B      2  Country -5.70 -19.67   10.913
6 Client B      3  Country  3.59 -18.95    9.318
7 Client C      1 Suburban  4.42 -16.31       NA
8 Client C      2 Suburban -5.75 -15.18   10.233
9 Client C      3 Suburban  3.57 -18.97   10.061
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem correctly, here is my attempt:

```
ddply(df, .(Name), function(d) {
    d <- d[order(d$Location), ]
    distance <- sqrt((diff(d$X))^2 + (diff(d$Y))^2)
    d$cum_distance <- cumsum(c(0, distance))
    return(d)
})
```

And below is the output:

```
      Name Sample Location     X      Y cum_distance
1 Client A      1     City  4.35 -15.43      0.00000
2 Client A      2     City -5.70 -19.67     10.90780
3 Client A      3     City  3.60 -20.49     20.24388
4 Client B      1  Country  4.36 -15.44      0.00000
5 Client B      2  Country -5.70 -19.67     10.91313
6 Client B      3  Country  3.59 -18.95     20.23099
7 Client C      1 Suburban  4.42 -16.31      0.00000
8 Client C      2 Suburban -5.75 -15.18     10.23259
9 Client C      3 Suburban  3.57 -18.97     20.29372
```